# How to reset password in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-authentication

I have an app called API where I want to create a "Forgot Password" button for the user to insert their email, and a password reset is sent to them.

In the same Django project, I have an application called users which implements this process in the backend.

How can Django Rest Framework be used to reset the password? Do I link the URLs of the users app or create new URLs in API app

Here is the users app urls.py

```
app_name = 'users'
urlpatterns = [
    path('password/', user_views.change_password, name='change_password'),
    path('password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset.html', success_url=reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_done')), name='password_reset'),
    path('password-reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'),name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html',success_url=reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_complete')),name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password-reset-complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'),name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

here is the main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('api.urls'), ),
    path('users/', include('users.urls'), ),
```

here is the api app urls.py

```
app_name = 'api'

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, basename='user')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('dj-rest-auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
    path('dj-rest-auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Dj Rest Auth already provide endpoint for reseting password, you have to use them.
You can find all endpoint in the documentation : https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_endpoints.html

In you case, `dj-rest-auth/password/reset/` in POST request with email as data will make what you want to